# Jwebunit and Wordpress

Tags: java, wordpress, htmlunit

I'm trying to login to my website which runs on wordpress using Jwebunit.

```
webPage.setBaseUrl("http://www.mywebsite.com");
webPage.beginAt("/wp-login.php");

webPage.setTextField("log", "myusername");
webPage.setTextField("pwd", "mypassword");
webPage.clickButton("wp-submit");
```

The above does not throw any errors, but the page does not get submitted. If I try a wrong password, it will throw the error, but when all values are correct, the submit does not go to the new page.

Any idea why this might be happening?